# MySQL query to get paid invoices

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL tables:

**invoices**

- invoice_id,
- invoice_number,
- invoice_description,
- invoice_value,
- invoice_date

**payments**

- payment_id
- payment_invoice_id
- payment_value
- payment_date

My goal is to make a single query that can retrieve all the invoices that have been paid in full (the invoice_value must match the sum of payment_value).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Invoices i
JOIN Payments p ON i.invoice_id = p.payment_invoice_id
GROUP BY i.invoice_id
HAVING i.invoice_value = SUM(p.payment_value);
```

PS: Be sure you use `NUMERIC(9,2)` for currency data.  Don't use `FLOAT`.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know about HAVING. Thank you.

Comment: i'd amend that with `i.invoice_value <= SUM(p.payment_value)`

Comment: @scones, why would you want the inequality?  The OP said he wants invoices that have been paid in full.

Comment: @BillKarwin fuzzy customers may pay more. in which case they have paid in full and some extra.

Comment: @scones, if that's the case, then you would want `i.invoice_value <= SUM(p.payment_value)`.

Comment: @Psyche, that's fine, DECIMAL and NUMERIC are synonyms.  Your 12 digits of precision mean the size of the column is slightly larger than it needs to be, but it's probably not important unless you have billions of rows.